# In python 3.x how do I remove a sub-string from a string in a list?

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, substring

I am making a program that reads in various pieces of information about a system and sorts it into a more concise and presentable format. The necessary information gets added to a list as it gets read, but I need to remove some data from certain list elements.

For example my list will have an element that looks like this:

```
['Software: 12.01 (built 2016-10-28 21:51:37+01:00)']
```

how do I remove everything after the 12.01 (or some other arbitrary sequence)?

Edit: I figured it out

```
with open('filename.txt') as f: 
    software_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f if 'Software:' in line]
for i in software_list:
    final_soft_list.append(i.split('(')[0])
print(final_soft_list)
```

the output gave me: [Software: 12.01]

Comment: You cannot remove after "_some other arbitrary sequence_". You must describe the sequence using, e.g., regular expressions.

Comment: Also, please include what you have tried

Comment: something like `myString[0].split('12.01')[0]` could do your job. Try tweeaking around.

Comment: @DYZ I said arbitrary because the information that comes after the version (12.01) will differ from system to system. Additionally, I am trying to do this with other, different, strings that get read in. I am trying to get it to remove any data after a certain point, and since the data will vary from system to system, I need some sort of wilcard or a way to say "only keep this part"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` module.

Assuming you want to replace substr for all the elements of a list, create a function like below:

```
import re

def remove_substr(input_list, substr):
    out_list = []
    for element in input_list:
        out_list.append(re.sub(substr,'',element))
    return out_list
```

Calling the function on the sample you posted:

```
In [1325]: l
Out[1325]: ['Software: 12.01 (built 2016-10-28 21:51:37+01:00)']

In [1330]: out_list = remove_substr(l, '12.01')

In [1331]: out_list
Out[1331]: ['Software:  (built 2016-10-28 21:51:37+01:00)']
```

If you want to remove anything after the pattern, you can do this:

```
In [1354]: def remove_substr(input_list, substr):
      ...:         out_list = []
      ...:         for element in input_list:
      ...:             out_list.append(element.split(substr)[0])
      ...:         return out_list
      ...:     

In [1355]: 

In [1355]: remove_substr(l,'12.01')
Out[1355]: ['Software: ']
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What if I want to remove the (built 2016-10-28 21:51:37+01:00) portion? The issue I am running into is that this will be run against a bunch of different systems so the build data will differ. How can I use some sort of wildcard to delete any data that comes after the version (in this case 12.01)?

Comment: Check my updated answer. I added another function. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: I used the split() method but did not need to use re. Thank you for your help